# Facebook: Line breaks (\n) work but also show up in feed

Tags: php, facebook

I've created some code that automatically posts one message a day on a facebook page of mine.
Those messages contain line breaks.
In my original text in the db the linebreaks are **`<br />`**, 
but my php code replaces the tag with a **`\n`**.

```
$quote = preg_replace('/(<br \/>)/',' \n',$quote);
```

Now, the **line breaks work** fine, except that **at the end of each line the `\n` shows** up, too! 
So on the facebook page feed it looks like this:

```
A good traveler leaves no tracks, \n
and a skillful speaker is well rehearsed. \n
```

Is my replace wrong? Or does anyone have a similar experience?

Thanks.

Comment: **[Read](http://il.php.net/types.string)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special characters like line breaks have to be in double quotes ([see php strings documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

```
$quote = preg_replace('/(<br \/>)/',"\n",$quote);
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/CYAPz).

Comment: They're called "special characters" not "invisible characters". :)